# dispatch_get_main_queue Deprecated in iOS 8

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, ios8

I very commonly write code following this pattern:

```
- (void)doLongTaskAsync:(CompletionBlock)completion
{
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        // Do Long Running Calculation

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion();
        });
    });
}
```

If `dispatch_get_main_queue` is deprecated, what is the replacement for this style of code? Is `NSOperationQueue` now the only means to thread code?

Comment: It is not deprecated per dispatch/queue.h Please show the error message.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014455    Search the text "/usr/include/dispatch/object.h" (without quotes)

Comment: it is not deprecated, it was just reimplemented as an inline function instead of a macro (for compatibility with Swift)

Comment: @das has the correct response. The API is not deprecated. This looks to be a problem solely with Apple's documentation generation picking up the deletion of the old macro. I've filed a Radar requesting the documentation be corrected.

Comment: It looks like Dad is correct. Can you make that an answer with a source so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments by [das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549715/das), this function is not deprecated, but refactored to be an inline function instead of a macro.